# Upgrading from VS2008 Pro to VS2010 Pro without MSDN

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm looking to upgrade from Visual Studio 2008 Pro to Visual Studio 2010 Pro *without* MSDN. On the [MSDN US site](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/professional) there's pricing for **Upgrade from Standard** for $299.

On the [UK MSDN site](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-gb/products/2010-editions/professional) however, the only options are to buy with MSDN for £484.99. Obviously a big difference in price there!

I can't find any info as to what qualifies for the **Upgrade from Standard** - anyone know about this? Or whether it's available in the UK?

thanks

Richard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really a programming question... (but somehow it is.. it's VS after all :P)

But: Have you considered calling the microsoft support or sending them an email? I bet they can give you the sophisticated info on that matter.

Comment: They have a presales department in the US that is really really really good and can answer this kind of questions. I think their phone number is listed somewhere on the MS site.

Comment: yeah I was going to do that tomorrow but thought I'd ask the experts on here first! Wasn't sure whether this would qualify as a programming question or not, but as you say, it is VS.

Comment: Can I give you a (somewhat unrelated) piece of advice? Never buy Visual Studio directly from MS or an MS authorized retailer. You'll always, always, always pay more. Either get your company to purchase it for you, or if you're freelance, get a copy through a wholesaler or better yet, second-hand.

Comment: And the 90-day fully-functional trial versions sort of keep on working if you just. Well suffice to say that with Visual Studio MS isn't so much concerned about casual piracy. I do NOT recommend that you pirate; I'm trying to point out that the intended audience here is a corporate one. Freelancers can always find a way to get this stuff cheaper. (Not that $500 or $1000 is so much to pay for your livelihood.)

Comment: @Swingline Rage - thanks. Actually I wouldn't ever buy direct anyway - was just looking for the info on there before searching out better prices.

Answer (score 1):

The `Upgrade from Standard` is for

```
*Special upgrade for Visual Studio 2005/2008 Standard Edition customers. Does not include MSDN.
```

If you want more info go to

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/buy

and just above the `BUY NOW` button on the left there will be a link to `Chat with a Representative`. They should be able to tell you if you can upgrade from 2008 Pro to 2010 Pro.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also not a MSDN member.  As the owner of Visual Studio 2008 Standard Edition, I was able to purchase a Visual Studio 2010 Professional license for $299.

I'm assuming your confusion is coming from the fact that you own VS 2008 Pro and not VS 2008 Standard.  I would think that you could take advantage of the same $299 offer, but as someone else said, I'd check with Microsoft sales first.

Comment: exactly my point, yes! I'll be checking with MS sales first (but not buying from them)

Answer (score -1):

I believe the upgrade is from VS 2010 Standard to VS 2010 Pro - not from earlier editions.

Comment: I don't think so - see my answer